# Как правильно сделать чтобы функция вызвалась 3 раза через каждые 3 секунды?

Tags: java, android

Нужно чтобы метод вызвался 3 раза через 3 секунды, но не останавливая главный поток

Answer (score 8, accepted):

На самом деле здесь много способов. Можно использовать любой инструмент для работы с потоками, просто выбрать какой удобней. Мне кажется, что такое очень легко сделать:

1. **Handler** + Runnable,  только Loop его должен крутиться не в Main потоке. Пример:

   ```
   final Handler handler = new Handler();
   handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           doSomething();
           count++;
           if (count <= 3) handler.postDelayed(this, 3000);
       }
   }, 3000);
   ```

мне кажется это самый быстрый нативный способ, чтоб сделать такое, также лучше написать Runnable отдельно ибо(лямбды), это не всегда будет так работать, ну это уже другое.

2. **Rx** + repeat ну и как альтернатива, как бы сделал я, например возьмем какой-нить api

   ```
   myApi
               .getRequestBody()
               .repeatWhen(h-> h.delay(3000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
               .takeUntil(stopPolling -> count < 3)
               .subscribe(this::showList);
   ```

Я написал сокращенный вариант, ну если вы используете Rx, то разберетесь сразу.

*ps:писал без IDE поправьте, если что X_X.*

Answer (score 6):

Например, вот так:

```
final Handler h = new Handler();
for (int i=1;i<numberOfTimes+1;i++) {
   h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            function();
        }
   },i*3000);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

А можно, наверное, и так?

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    ourMethod();
                }

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }.start();
}

public static void ourMethod() {
    //do smth
}
```

Создаем новый поток, выполняем в цикле три вызова, усыпляем поток на три секунды и всё это в бесконечном цикле (условие остановки или прерывания потока за вами). Стартуем новый поток.

Comment: это лучший вариант